# c# request.querystring add and remove few key value pairs in an efficient manner?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We want to remove query string (a,b,c,d) and add query string (z). For example:

Input:  `/example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5&f=6`
Output: `/example.com/?&e=5&f=6&z=6`

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
    {
        if (key != "a" && key != "b" && key != "c" && key != "d")
        {
            dict.Add(key, Request.QueryString[key]);
        }
    }
queryString = string.Join("&", dict.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString ))
{
    searchViewModel.CurrQS += "&z=6";
}
```

I have done this so far. But is it worth converting this to dictionary and then to string for this. Any other better method?

Comment: is it asp.net ??? or simple c# code

Comment: Try Regex.Replace?

Comment: @PranayRana: asp.net

Comment: try out opt given , let me know if it works for you or not

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(queryString, @"(\?[abcd]=.+?|&[abcd]=.+?(?=&)|&[abcd]=.+?$)", "");`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
    {
        if (key != "a" && key != "b" && key != "c" && key != "d")
        {
            dict.Add(key, Request.QueryString[key]);
        }
    }

queryString = Request.RawUrl.Split(new[] {'?'})[0] +
              string.Join("&", dict.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString ))
{
    queryString  += "&z=6";
}
```

---

Easy way out of this is, if you have url then do this:

```
var stringURL = Request.RawUrl.Split(new[] {'?'});
var urlwithoutQuerystring=stringURL.First();
var newUrl = urlwithoutQuerystring + "?c=abc"
```

or do like this

```
var stringURL = Request.RawUrl.Split(new[] {'?'})[0];
var newUrl = strinULR + "?c=abc"
```

Comment: how would this remove query string keys a,b,c,d?

Comment: @maverick - if you do this var stringURL = Request.RawUrl.Split(new[] {'?'})[0]; it will give you row url without querystring ...so your query string will get remove ..not need to worry about it..if you want to store data then just store it and replace

Comment: @maverick - updated for you

Comment: @maverick - is that worked for you ??

Comment: please provide reason of putting - 1??